# Display an avator of a GitHub account in SourceTree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I want to display a Gravatar image in SourceTree. My github commits use this e-mail adress: mboom@users.noreply.github.com. I already set a gravator for the primary e-mail, but SourceTree does not display the right avatar. How can I set the avatar for this e-mail adress in SourceTree?

Comment: Did you check your SourceTree Settings? Repository -> Repository Settings -> Advanced -> And check if SourceTree is using the global settings with the right user or not..

Comment: Thanks for help, but those settings are correct. The issue happens when I merge a pull-request on the website of github. After the merge I can see the merge commit in SourceTree, but with the settings of GitHub. So also that e-mail address.

Comment: Also I received an message of the GitHub staff. It is impossible to register that e-mail address in Gravatar and choose an icon by your own. The only solution is that SourceTree should use the GitHub avatar and not an avatar from Gravatar. Conclusion: there is no solution yet for this issue.

Answer (score 3):

At this moment it is impossible to configure an email using  `@users.noreply.github.com` on [gravatar.com](https://gravatar.com)

This is due to security and technical limitations. Gravatar will allow you to register only email addresses that you own and that you can verify.

Due to this `noreply` addresses cannot be added on Gravatar.

Current alternative is to use GitHub avatar service in your client.

Answer (score -3):

You need to delete the avatar cache of SourceTree:

1. Go to http://en.gravatar.com/ create your account and upload the avatar image files that map to your emails.
2. Close Source Tree
3. Delete the cache file (or delete all files) inside path C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\cache\img
4. Open Source Tree. Now you got what you want!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't work. Step 1 fails.

Comment: I use an private emailaddress in SourceTree and mapped a gravatar. This works, because SourceTree uses that emailaddress when I perform actions like commit. The problem occurs when I merge pull-request. These requests are submitted on the website of github. Also merging pull-requests need te bo done on the website of github. Github uses the *@users.noreply.github.com emailaddress.

Comment: Mapping a gravatar image to an *@users.noreply.github.com emailaddress is not possible. Gravatar sends a link to that emailaddress to confirm you use that emailaddress. It is not possible to receive emails on the *@users.noreply.github.com emailaddress. That is why this solution does not work. But thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, you are correct. My solution only works when you have a private email address.

Comment: Just a idea. According to past experience, the email without formal user name goes to email Administrator. Maybe you could ask Git Hub related person to confirm the link for you.